# Problem with citing in biblatex, document just shows the citation key

Tags: biblatex

I'm having quite a lot of trouble with correct citation in my document. Everything compiles fine, but it just shows the citation key in bold letter instead of the actual citation. Also, nothing shows up in the bibliography, even with `\nocite{*}`. Here is the relevant code:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber, autocite=footnote, style=authortitle]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{REFS.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{Rouse2019}
\printbibliography[type=online, title={Online}]
\end{document}
```

I'm kind of at a loss. When my friend compiles my document, the citation shows up for him. If nothing works, I'll just have him compile it and send that to my teacher lol.

Thank you all for your help

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did:

1. Compiled the file (I use TeXStudio, not sure how it is with other programs)
2. Opened the Terminal in MikTeX
3. Ran the command "biber (path to main file without `.tex`)"
4. Waited until the command was done (or maybe smashed on my keyboard a little bit)
5. Compiled the file again
6. And the citation is now there!